# Help comparing float member variables using Comparators

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, comparable

I am able to compare Strings fine, but would like to know how I can rank floating point numbers?

getChange() returns a String. I want to be able to sort descending. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
package org.stocktwits.helper;

import java.util.Comparator;

import org.stocktwits.model.Quote;

public class ChangeComparator implements Comparator<Quote>
{
    public int compare(Quote o1, Quote o2) {
        float change1 = Float.valueOf(o1.getChange());
        float change2 = Float.valueOf(o2.getChange());

        if (change1 < change2) return -1;
        if (change1 == change2) return 0; // Fails on NaN however, not sure what you want
        if (change2 > change2) return 1;
    }
}
```

I am getting the compile time error:

```
This method must return a result of type int    ChangeComparator.java
```

Comment: Aside from the NaN issue, you have no guaranteed return statement in your code.  Realistically you do, but the compiler cannot tell that because you have three different if statements.  It can't evaluate those until runtime, so it thinks you could actually get past the last if statement and there's no return clause.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read the javadoc of [`Comparator#compare()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method.

> Compares its two arguments for order. **Returns a negative integer, zero or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to or greater than the second.**

So, *basically*:

```
float change1 = o1.getChange();
float change2 = o2.getChange();
if (change1 < change2) return -1;
if (change1 > change2) return 1;
return 0;
```

Or if you like conditional operators:

```
return o1.getChange() < o2.getChange() ? -1 
     : o1.getChange() > o2.getChange() ? 1 
     : 0;
```

You however need to take account with [`Float.NaN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NaN). I am not sure how you'd like to have them ordered. First? Last? Equally?

Comment: watch out for Float.NaN!  I'm presuming your data doesn't have NaNs, but since NaN on one side of any comparison will always return false (even Float.NaN==Float.NaN is false!), you might want a Float.isNaN(change1) or whatever check.  otherwise the sort will be apparently random if there are NaN's involved.

Comment: I am getting the compile time error (see updated code in my question): This method must return a result of type int ChangeComparator.java

Comment: The compilation error speaks for itself. You need to make sure that it **always** returns an `int`. I'll edit the example.

Answer (score 18):

How about this:

```
public class ChangeComparator implements Comparator<Quote>
{
    public int compare(Quote o1, Quote o2) {
        Float change1 = Float.valueOf(o1.getChange());
        Float change2 = Float.valueOf(o2.getChange());
        return change1.compareTo(change2);
    }
}
```

Note that Java 1.4 introduced [`Float#compare(float, float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-) (and an equivalent in `Double`), which can be pretty much used directly:

```
public class ChangeComparator implements Comparator<Quote>
{
    public int compare(Quote o1, Quote o2) {
        return Float.compare(o1.getChange(), o2.getChange());
    }
}
```

(After editing, I notice that @BorislavGizdov has mentioned this in his answer already.)

---

Also worth noting that Java 8 [`Comparator#comparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Comparator#comparingDouble(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) provide a straightforward way of constructing these comparators directly.

```
Comparator<Quote> changeComparator = Comparator.comparing(Quote::getChange);
```

Will compare using boxed `Float` values.

```
Comparator<Quote> changeComparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(Quote::getChange);
```

Will compare using `float` values promoted to `double` values.

Given that there is no `Comparator#comparingFloat(...)`, my preference would be to use the `comparingDouble(...)` method, as this only involves primitive type conversion, rather than boxing.

Comment: This is the best answer - delegate the comparison to Float's compareTo.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Float.compare(float f1, float f2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-):

> ```
>   public static int compare(float f1, float f2)
> ```
>
> Compares the two specified float values. Returns the value 0 if f1 is numerically equal to f2; a value less than 0 if f1 is numerically less than f2; and a value greater than 0 if f1 is numerically greater than f2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tc = input.nextInt();
        int alpha = 0;
        while (tc-- > 0) {
            int ttc = input.nextInt();
            int sort = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            Vector<student> v = new Vector<>();
            alpha++;
            while (ttc-- > 0) {
                String name = input.next();
                int weit = input.nextInt();
                int age = input.nextInt();
                float hight = input.nextFloat();

                v.add(new student(name, weit, age, hight));
            }
            Collections.sort(v);
            int count = 0;
            System.out.println("CENARIO {" + alpha + "}");
            for (student s : v) {
                System.out.print((count + 1) + " - ");
                System.out.println(s.name);
                count++;
                if (count == sort) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class student implements Comparable<student> {

        String name;
        int weit;
        int age;
        float hight;

        public student(String name, int weit, int age, float hight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.weit = weit;
            this.age = age;
            this.hight = hight;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(student t) {
            if (this.weit - t.weit != 0) {
                return t.weit - this.weit;
            }
            if (this.age - t.age != 0) {
                return this.age - t.age;
            }
            if (this.hight - t.hight != 0) {
                return Float.compare(this.hight, t.hight);
            }
            return this.name.compareTo(t.name);

        }
    }
}
```