# Java 8 sort float values

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have a list of employees which had different experiences like

> 5.0,3.3,5.5,5.6,4.5 etc..

When I am trying to sort max to min experience by using `Math.round` it's giving the wrong result like:

> 5.6,5.0,5.5,5.3,4.5 etc..

I want the result like:

> 5.6,5.5,5.3,5.0,4.5 etc..

Here I used `Collections.sort` like:

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Emp>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Emp t, Emp t1) {
            return Math.round(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience()); // which giving wrong results
//          return Float.compare(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience()); // which is not working
        }
    });
```

Here `t1.getExperience()` will give you float result.

Comment: see this answer may be helpfull
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705372/7328984

Comment: 1. Comparator of Profile is comparing Emp1 and Emp2 class objects 2. What is the experience attribute type is not specificed.

Comment: How will that be a `Comparator<Profile>` when you're comparing `Employee`s?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I mentioned in last line it is of type float

Comment: @daniu Sorry it's by mistaken, updated now check

Comment: java.lang.Float already implements Comparable, any reason you want to do it this way. And not reverse compare the two values?

Comment: `Math.round(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience())` does not work because it will consider `5.3` and `5.0` equal, due to rounding. This trick only works with integers.

Comment: Yep finally, I found it the mistake is `-` should be replaced with ','

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Math.round(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience())` doesn't compare the two numbers, so I don't know what you were expecting to achieve.

You are supposed to use:

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, new Comparator<Emp>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Emp t, Emp t1) {
        return Float.compare(t1.getExperience(), t.getExperience());
    }
});
```

Note that the parameters passed to `Float.compare` are in the opposite order compared to the parameters of the wrapping `compare` method, which will produce sorting by **descending** order.

Comment: Maybe he wanted `Comparator.comparing(e -> Math.round(e.getExperience()))`?

Comment: @daniu the posted example shows regular descending order, so it doesn't look like Math.round() is required.

Comment: When I tried above it is saying compare (float, float) in Float cannot be applied to (float) @Eran

Comment: @ShylendraMadda you didn't try the above. Learn the difference between one parameter and two.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda in the code you posted you tried `Float.compare(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience())`, when it should be `Float.compare(t1.getExperience(), t.getExperience());`

Comment: And as I mentioned already in my question in commented line `return Float.compare(t.getExperience() - t1.getExperience()); // which is not working`

Comment: @ShylendraMadda `-` and `,` are not the same

Comment: Ohh OMG that is the stupidity in my eyes.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Or just `Collections.sort(employeeList, Comparator.comparingDouble(Emp::getExperience) .reversed());` as there is no benefit to use `float` instead of `double` for temporary values…

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
 employeeList.sort(Comparator. comparingDouble(Employee::getExperience).reversed());
```

But it is advised not to mutate existing collections, but to create a new one instead. So with a stream, as an example:

```
Comparator<Employee> byExperience = Comparator. comparingDouble(Employee::getExperience).reversed(); 
List<Employee> employeeList = ...;
List<Employee> sortedByExperienceEmployeeList =
 employeeList.sorted(byExperience)
.toList();
```

It will produce:

> 5.6
> 5.5
> 5.0
> 4.5
> 3.3

Comment: Better use `Comparator.comparingDouble`. Avoids unnecessary boxing.